# null listview appears on item click?

Tags: android, listview

when i click item on gridview it should show me list of upcoming game but it give me null listview ... why?

this is the code:

```
private View.OnClickListener getGamesByDate(final String[] date, final ListView luListView) {
            return new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // send post request to get game by date and Plyid
                    Log.e("DATE", date[0]+"-"+date[1]+"-"+date[2]);
                    String dt = date[0] + "-" + date[1] + "-" + date[2];
                    //  2016-02-18 the date in the hashmap of games
                    GameEvent gm = ViewUpcomingGmsAsyncTask.hashUpcoming.get(dt);
                   // ViewUpcomingGmsAsyncTask playerEvents = new ViewUpcomingGmsAsyncTask(new ProgressDialog(mContext), mContext,gridview );
                    Log.e("tabs",""+luListView);

                    ProgressDialog progress= new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                  /*  GamesAdapter upcomingAdapter = new GamesAdapter(arrayLists,mContex,lvupcoming,3);
                    lvupcoming.setAdapter(upcomingAdapter);*/

                    new ViewUpcomingGmsAsyncTask(progress,mContext,luListView).execute();
                   // Log.e("tabs",""+luListView);


                    if (gm!=null){
                        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                        mBundle.putSerializable("gm",gm);
                        GameDetailsFragment GameDetails=GameDetailsFragment.newInstance();
                        GameDetails.setArguments(mBundle);
                        mContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                                GameDetails,"gmDetails").addToBackStack("gmDetails").commit();

                    }
    }
};}
```

the all code:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import fastplay.netcharizma.com.fastplay.Fragments.GameDetailsFragment;
import fastplay.netcharizma.com.fastplay.R;
import fastplay.netcharizma.com.fastplay.Utils.GameActions;
import fastplay.netcharizma.com.fastplay.asyncTask.CalLstAsynck;
import fastplay.netcharizma.com.fastplay.asyncTask.ViewUpcomingGmsAsyncTask;
import fastplay.netcharizma.com.fastplay.asyncTask.loginAsync;
import fastplay.netcharizma.com.fastplay.bean.GameEvent;

/**
* Created by root on 7/2/2015.
*/
public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private FragmentActivity mContext;
private java.util.Calendar month;
public GregorianCalendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
/**
 * calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view
 */
public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
private int firstDay;
private int maxWeeknumber;
private int maxP;
private int calMaxP;
private int lastWeekDay;
private int leftDays;
private int mnthlength;
private String itemvalue, curentDateString;
private DateFormat df;
private GameActions gmActions;
private  ArrayList<GameEvent> ev;

private ArrayList<String> items;
public static List<String> dayString;
private View previousView;
ListView lvupcoming;


public CalendarAdapter(FragmentActivity c, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar)     {

    CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<>();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    month = monthCalendar;
    selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
    mContext = c;
    month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
    refreshDays();
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
    for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
            items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
        }
    }
    this.items = items;
}

public int getCount() {
    if(dayString != null && dayString.size() >0) return dayString.size(); else return 0;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dayString.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    TextView dayView;




    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
        // attributes
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);
        lvupcoming= (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvupcoming);


    }
   // convertView.setTag();
    dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    ImageView icon= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
    // separates day string into parts.
    String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
    // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
    String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
    // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
    if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
        // setting off days to white color.
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        dayView.setClickable(false);
        dayView.setFocusable(false);
    } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        dayView.setClickable(false);
        dayView.setFocusable(false);
    } else {
        // setting curent month's days in blue color.
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
        setSelected(v);
        previousView = v;
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
    }
    dayView.setText(gridvalue);

    // create date string for comparison
    String date = dayString.get(position);

    if (date.length() == 1) {
        date = "0" + date;
    }

    String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
    if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
        monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
    }
    // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
    ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
    if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(date)) {
        iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    v.setOnClickListener(getGamesByDate(separatedTime));

    v.setOnClickListener(getGamesByDate(separatedTime,lvupcoming));

    return v;
}

private View.OnClickListener getGamesByDate(final String[] date) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // send post request to get game by date and Plyid
            Log.e("DATE", date[0]+"-"+date[1]+"-"+date[2]);
            String dt = date[0] + "-" + date[1] + "-" + date[2];
            //  2016-02-18 the date in the hashmap of games
            GameEvent gm = ViewUpcomingGmsAsyncTask.hashUpcoming.get(dt);




        if (gm!=null){
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putSerializable("gm",gm);
            GameDetailsFragment GameDetails=GameDetailsFragment.newInstance();
            GameDetails.setArguments(mBundle);
            mContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    GameDetails,"gmDetails").addToBackStack("gmDetails").commit();
        }
        }
    };}
        private View.OnClickListener getGamesByDate(final String[] date, final ListView luListView) {
            return new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // send post request to get game by date and Plyid
                    Log.e("DATE", date[0]+"-"+date[1]+"-"+date[2]);
                    String dt = date[0] + "-" + date[1] + "-" + date[2];
                    //  2016-02-18 the date in the hashmap of games
                    GameEvent gm = ViewUpcomingGmsAsyncTask.hashUpcoming.get(dt);
                   // ViewUpcomingGmsAsyncTask playerEvents = new ViewUpcomingGmsAsyncTask(new ProgressDialog(mContext), mContext,gridview );
                    Log.e("tabs",""+luListView);

                    ProgressDialog progress= new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                  /*  GamesAdapter upcomingAdapter = new GamesAdapter(arrayLists,mContex,lvupcoming,3);
                    lvupcoming.setAdapter(upcomingAdapter);*/

                    new ViewUpcomingGmsAsyncTask(progress,mContext,luListView).execute();
                   // Log.e("tabs",""+luListView);


                    if (gm!=null){
                        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                        mBundle.putSerializable("gm",gm);
                        GameDetailsFragment GameDetails=GameDetailsFragment.newInstance();
                        GameDetails.setArguments(mBundle);
                        mContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                                GameDetails,"gmDetails").addToBackStack("gmDetails").commit();

                    }
    }
};}

public View setSelected(View view) {
    if (previousView != null) {
        previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
    }
    previousView = view;
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_select);

    return view;

}

public void refreshDays() {
    // clear items
    items.clear();
    dayString.clear();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
    // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
    firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    // finding number of weeks in current month.
    maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
    mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
    maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
    calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
    /**
     * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three
     * month's (previous,current,next) dates.
     */
    pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
    /**
     * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
     */
    pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

    /**
     * filling calendar gridview.
     */
    for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {
        itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
        pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
        dayString.add(itemvalue);
    }
}

private int getMaxP() {
    int maxP;
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
    }
    maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return maxP;
}


private void plotDataOnGridPerMonth(){
    // get string months string arrays and match it with hashmap of dates=>events
    // to acquire game object then redirect to game details fragment


}
```

the logcat
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qSbUozI6X9WkF2WkpLcHdaOEU/view](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive)

i want to display listview with the date of gameevent....
 anyone can find the solution of this problem ?

Comment: share your error log to better help.

Comment: The code you shared is too long, and it's hard to see the relevant parts. Please reduce it to the minimum amount of code related to the problem. This may also help you solve it yourself.